# Use mutated vowel in html helpfile

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

A HTML helpfile is not displayed in AX Help ( F1 in AX if HelpServer is configured ), as soon as a mutated vowel is used in the document:

`<p>Testentry A</p>` is displayed as `Testentry A`

`<p>Testentry &uuml;</p>` - the whole document is not displayed

`<p>Testentry &#124;</p>` is again displayed as `Testentry |`

Is there a setting or something to be able to use mutated vowels in documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this one?

`<p>Testentry Ü</p>`

Comment: Yes, I have. Result is the same as &uuml;